# How to Convert User input to Encoder value type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have MVC 5 project that use System.Drawing; System.Drawing.Imaging; I want the user to select image quality when it is jpeg This is my approach:

```
   Encoder quality = Encoder.Quality; //quality should be user input
                    var ratio = new EncoderParameter(quality, 100L);
                    var codecParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
                    codecParams.Param[0] = ratio;
                    convertedImage.Save(outputImagePath, GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg), codecParams);
```

Due to some use cases I have  **public async Task bool** and I can't declare encoder parameter.
Thus my question: How to convert string(user input) to encoder.
If we want to convert string to Int, simple:

```
var name = Convert.ToInt32(userinput);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @snow_FFFFFF answer I used this approach:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
//If you pass quality as int then you won't need to parse it                                         BitConverter.GetBytes(int.Parse(quality)).CopyTo(bytes, 0);
result=new Guid(bytes);
Encoder qquality = new Encoder(result);
var ratio = new EncoderParameter(qquality, 100L);
var codecParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
codecParams.Param[0] = ratio;
string outputPNGPath = Path.Combine(fileNameResultDirectory, "00" + pageNumber.ToString() + ".jpeg");
pdf2PNG.Save(outputPNGPath, GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg), codecParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to get values like "quality" vs. "colordepth", you could do something like this, as long as you know the possible values:

```
switch (userInput.ToLower())
{
     case "quality":
         quality = Encoder.Quality;
         break;
     case "colordepth":
         quality = Encoder.ColorDepth;
         break;
     // etc....
}
```

Taking a quick look, it look like the Encoder constructor requires a guid.  So, if you wanted to create the encoder from a guid value, the following tries to parse the userInput and create an Encoder if it is a valid guid.  It seems like you may actually need to make sure the guid is a valid value for the constructor as well.

```
Encoder quality;
if (Guid.TryParse(userInput, out Guid result))
{
    quality = new Encoder(result);
}
else
{
    // default to something if userInput isn't valid?
}
```